# Injecting code into a method that is overridden (Java)

Tags: java, minecraft

I have this:

```
public class Superclass {
  public int getMaxLevel() {
    return 1;
  }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
  public int getMaxLevel() {
    return 4;
  }
}
```

and I need it to be this:

```
public class Superclass {
  public int getMaxLevel() {
    return 3; //injected
    //return 1; //original
  }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
  public int getMaxLevel() {
    return 3; //injected
    //return 4; //original
  }
}
```

Both superclass and subclass are in a library. Also, due to my use-case being a Minecraft mod, I aim at compatibility, so it needs to be done in the superclass, not the subclass.

I would prefer answers that use Java only (require no external libraries).

Edit: Modding framework used is Forge 1.16.5, and I do not have access to all subclasses (so there may be additional classes extending Superclass), which is why the injection needs to be performed in Superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the modding toolchain you're using, but if it's Fabric or Forge 1.16.5 the `Mixin` bytecode weaving framework will let you do what you're looking for. Read more about [Mixin](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:mixin_introduction) on the fabric wiki.

```
@Mixin(Superclass.class)
public class SuperclassMixin {

   @Inject(method = "getMaxLevel", at = @At("RETURN"), cancellable = true)
   public int getMaxLevelReturnInject(CallbackInfoReturnable<Integer> ci) {
      ci.setReturnValue(3);
   }

}
```

and repeat for Subclass.

Comment: First, I am using Forge 1.16.5.
Second, that's the solution I had until now, but it won't work, since I do not want to do it in the subclass. That's the very point of the question. No subclass editing, because I am not able to get all of them. (Except there is a way to create a mixin at runtime?)

Comment: @IchHabeHunger54 You should probably write that in your question....